# Redirect subdomain to subfolder of another subdomain

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

What I want to do is take traffic that is going to shop.mywebsite.com and redirect or rewrite (I'm not sure of the terminology) the domain to be www.mywebsite.com/shop. Both shop.* and www.* are separate web applications (nopCommerce and Umbraco respectively) that don't seem to cooperate when I've tried to nest them. Both applications are in a Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5 environment.

I've searched around stackoverflow and what I've found is a lot of answers to mapping the other direction (ie subfolder to a subdomain) but that's not what I'm looking for as far as I understand the problem.

The end goal is to combine the SEO reputation of the shop subdomain into the www subdomain. I readily admit that I might have this all backwards and am willing to try any suggestions I'm offered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [URL rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx).

> URL rewriting is the process of
>   intercepting an incoming Web request
>   and redirecting the request to a
>   different resource. When performing
>   URL rewriting, typically the URL being
>   requested is checked and, based on its
>   value, the request is redirected to a
>   different URL

EDIT:
You may also want to check [URL Rewrite Extension](http://www.microsoft.com/web/spotlight/urlrewriter/) from microsoft, it will fix common SEO problems that your site might have.